# mixing of five songs in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

In my app I have five buttons and every button have five songs. In the main view there is a star (contains five ends) in the view. When the user drags the button to the end of the star it should play the song. Link this same has four and we want to mix those songs into a file like a ringtone saved it in to a tmp directory. I had tried a lot for this but I'm unable to get an answer to the problem.

The code I'm using is:

```
- (void) doAudioCallback: (NSTimer *)timer {
    NSString *resName1 = @"drum1.aif"; 
    NSString *resName2 = @"drum2.aif"; 
    NSString *resPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resName1 ofType:nil];
    NSString *resPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resName2 ofType:nil];
    NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory(); 
    NSString *tmpFilename = @"MixedoftwoSongs.aif"; 
    NSString *tmpPath = [tmpDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFilename]; 

    OSStatus status;
    if (status == OSSTATUS_MIX_WOULD_CLIP) { 
    } else {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tmpPath]; 

        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
        NSLog(@"wrote mix file of size %d : %@", [urlData length], tmpPath); 

        AVAudioPlayer *avAudioObj = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil]; 
        self.avAudio = avAudioObj; 
        [avAudioObj prepareToPlay]; 
        [avAudioObj play]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I had done only two music files,i need to mix five files into a file as ringtone.for this u need PCMixer header file.

Comment: - (void) doAudioCallback: (NSTimer *)timer
{
 NSString *resName1 = @"drum1.aif";
   NSString *resName2 = @"drum2.aif";
   NSString *resPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resName1 ofType:nil];
 NSString *resPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resName2 ofType:nil];
     NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
 NSString *tmpFilename = @"MixedoftwoSongs.aif";
 NSString *tmpPath = [tmpDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFilename];
    OSStatus status;

Comment: if (status == OSSTATUS_MIX_WOULD_CLIP)
    {
 }
    else
        
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tmpPath];
  
  NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  
  NSLog(@"wrote mix file of size %d : %@", [urlData length], tmpPath);
  
  AVAudioPlayer *avAudioObj = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
        self.avAudio = avAudioObj;
  
  [avAudioObj prepareToPlay];
  [avAudioObj play];
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Perform Selector to delay your each audio
[self performSelector:@selector(yourmethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

Comment: can you send the code mixing for five songs into has a ringtone